# How to cut contour lines at the edge of a data source

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, gdal-contour

I have calculated some contour-lines using `gdal-contour` for two elevation model into a Postgis database. One is high res and the other lower res. Now I am seeing problems at the edge of my high resolution data-source where lines are creating a black border. See the attached image.

It seems as if the lines of the high resolution model continue over the edge, as if there has been a massive drop in altitude and, therefore, there are so many lines stacked on one of another.

My question now is: Can I somehow cut those lines? I thought I might be able to use the data part of the GeoTiff that I used for my high resolution contour-lines to generate a shape. Then shrink the shape by let's say 10m or so and use that shape to cut my contour line?!?
Is that somehow possible using PostGIS and gdal?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `gdal_polygonize.py` to extract the shape of the nodata area (or the ! nodata) area into a polygon, you can use `ST_Buffer()` in PostGIS with a **negative** parameter to shrink that area back a little and then `ST_Intersection()` to clip the contour lines with it.